# Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

**exception:**

> g.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
>   bean with name 'utenteDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.mauro.soclib.dao.UtenteDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans...">
   <context:annotation-config />     
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.mauro" />
    <http auto-config='true' >
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/paginaConGrafica**" access="ROLE_USER" />


        <form-login login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/paginaConGrafica"
            authentication-failure-url="/error-login.html" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/index" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="restAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.mauro.soclib.security.customAuthenticationProvider"  autowire="byType">
    </beans:bean>



    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider
        ref="restAuthenticationProvider" />
     </authentication-manager>



</beans:beans>
```

**servlet**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mauro.soclib" />
   <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social_libreria" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="1234" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="UtenteValidator" class="com.mauro.soclib.validator.UtenteFormValidator" />


    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:message" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- Scan for the domain objects with the ORM annotation -->  
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mauro.soclib" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- link al config file security -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
      <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
         <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
      </init-param>      
   </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



    <!-- specifiche della servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Show your servlet configuration

Answer (score 0):

Add this entries to your dispatcher servlet,

```
<bean id="utenteDAO" class="path" />
<bean id="utenteDAOImplementation class" class="path" />
```

it is throwing error because you have not autowired the dependencies

**EDIT:**

try defining the session factory,

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("sessionFactory")
public void seSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```

Comment: thank's and sorry for my bad english  but the problem:Error creating bean with name 'utenteDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.mauro.soclib.dao.UtenteDAO.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations

Comment: i got your error .. have you tried adding those beans to your dispatcher

Comment: I tried to enter but the problem remains); 
it seems that the session factory located in spring-security.xml

Comment: where I insert it in the provider for authentication?

Comment: read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup

Comment: hello I've seen and I've added the setting of the session factory but does not change anything except the same 
There is some but not a way to share the same session factory?

Answer (score -1):

change the location of the project folder and set  system path and path properties accordingly .It works in our case.But we are unable to find the exact reason.